# How can I update image from nodejs with multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, multer

[Worked for posting method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMSzt.jpg)

[Still don't know how to make it work on edit/update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkqjH.jpg)

Here's my attempt

```js
//route for handling product edit view
router.get('/edit/:id', upload.single('image'), async (request, response)=>{
    let product = await Product.findById(request.params.id);
    response.render('edit', { product: product });
});

//route for handling product edit
router.put('/:id', upload.single('image'), async (request, response)=>{
    request.product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id);
    let product = request.product;
    product.name = request.body.name;
    product.price = request.body.price;
    product.stock = request.body.stock;
    product.img = request.file.filename;

    try {
        product = await product.save();
        //redirect to show route
        response.redirect(`/products/${product.slug}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.redirect('/products/edit/${product.id}', { product: product });
    }
});
```

but it produces error

```js
(node:10876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at E:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Projects\Jannah Firdaus\jf-server\routes\products.js:76:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your PUT request is sending `multipart/form-data` bodies? Otherwise multer can't read it. Try adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form element or set your `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: You're right! I Should've added enctype='multipart/form-data' on the edit form in the first place, appreicate the help!!!